# Multiple validacion Regex en Laravel

Tags: laravel, regex, validación

Tengo una función que me valida todo a nivel de Frontend con Javascript pero necesito también validarlo en Backend con Laravel y Regex.
La funcion es la siguiente:

```js
$('input[type=password]').keyup(function() {
  //Captura el valor de la variable escrita en tiempo real
  var pswd = $(this).val();

  var tieneOchoCaracteres = pswd.length;
  var tieneDosLetras = (pswd.match(/[a-z]{1}/ig) || []).length >= 2;
  var tieneMayus = /[A-Z]/.test(pswd);
  var tieneDosNumeros = pswd.match(/\d\D+\d/g);
  var tieneDosNumerosConsecutivos = pswd.match(/\d{2,}/);
  // var tieneDosNumeros = (pswd.match(/\d/g) || []).length >= 2;
  var tieneDosEspeciales = pswd.match(/[%_\-&#=\$@]\w+[%_\-&#=$@]/);
  var tieneDosEspecialesConsecutivos = pswd.match(/[%_\-&#=\$@]{2,}/);
  //var tieneSimbolos = (pswd.match(/[%_\-&\#=\$@]/g) || []).length >= 2;
     
     //validar el tamaño mayor a 8 caracteres
     if (tieneOchoCaracteres >= 8) {
         $('#length').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
     } else {
         $('#length').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
     }

     //Validar Letras
     //Esta expresión verifica que se haya ingresado al menos dos letra de la A a la Z (en mayúsculas) o de la A a la Z (en minúsculas)
     if (tieneDosLetras) {
         $('#letras').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
     } else {
         $('#letras').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
     }

     //Validar Mayusculas
     //Esta expresion se verifica para asegurarse de que se haya ingresado al menos una letra mayúscula
     if (tieneMayus) {
         $('#mayusculas').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
     } else {
         $('#mayusculas').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
     }

     //Validar Numeros
     //Esto comprobará si hay dígitos del 0 al 9
     if (tieneDosNumeros && !tieneDosNumerosConsecutivos) {
         $('#numeros').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
     } else {
         $('#numeros').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
     }

     //Validar caracteres especiales
     //Esto comprobará si hay caracteres especiales y NO consecutivos
     if (tieneDosEspeciales && !tieneDosEspecialesConsecutivos) {
         $('#simbolos').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
     } else {
         $('#simbolos').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
     }
     
 }).focus(function() {
     $('#pswd_info').show();
 }).blur(function() {
     $('#pswd_info').hide();
 });
```

Ahora la pregunta es.
¿Como aplico todas esta reglas de Regex a nivel de backend solo a la contraseña?

La única validación que tengo para la contraseña es:

```
if (!empty($request->password)) {
        $request->validate([
        'password'      => 'alpha_num|max:15',
    ]);
        $actualizacion['password'] = bcrypt($request->password);
    }
```

¿Pero puedo colocar toda la regla de regex en una sola como sigue?

```
'password'      => 'alpha_num|max:15',/[a-z]{1}|\d\D+\d|[%_\-&#=\$@]\w+[%_\-&#=$@]|etc...'
```

Agradezco su ayuda.
Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

La forma correcta de definir una regla de validación de este tipo debe ser:

```
$request->validate([
    'password' =>
        array(
            'required',
            'regex:/[a-z]{1}/',
            'regex:/[A-Z]/',
            'regex:/\d\D+\d/',
            'regex:/[%_\-&#=\$@]\w+[%_\-&#=$@]/'
        ),
];
```

Y así sucesivamente para todas las reglas regex que se tenga.

Answer (score 1):

En la documentación oficial no hacen incapie en regex, pero hablan de dos cosas, en la validación se acepta un array para validar y especifican como se realiza el regex, de esa forma puedes construir tu propio regex multinivel, algo asi

`'password' => [
        'required',
        'alpha_num',
        'max:15'
        'regex:/[a-z]{1}/ig) || []',
        'regex:/[A-Z]/',
        'regex:/\d\D+\d/g',
        'regex:/\d{2,}/',
        'regex:/[%_\-&#=\$@]\w+[%_\-&#=$@]/',
        'regex:/[%_\-&#=\$@]{2,}/',
      ],`

esa es la forma en que lo podrías hacer (no he probado si funcionan esos regex tal cual, pero con eso tienes una idea), igual deberías ir probando de a poco, de todas formas esto tiene un inconveniente bastante grande, los mensajes de error que regresaras, ya que haces varias validaciones iguales y por lo tanto no tienes forma de decir que mensaje debe retornar por cada uno, a lo cual le veo dos soluciones, o haces custom-validation-rules o haces grupos de validación, validas una cosa y luego otra y así vas

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#custom-validation-rules
 https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#after-validation-hook

Answer (score 0):

El $request->validate te quedaría:

```
$request->validate([
    'password' => 'alpha_num|max:15',
    'regex:/[a-z]{1}|\d\D+\d|[%_\-&#=\$@]\w+[%_\-&#=$@]|etc...'
]);
```

Para laravel 5.6, documentación oficial: (https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-regex)

También puedes probar en una línea, así:

```
$request->validate(['password'=>'alpha_num|max:15|regex:/[a-z]{1}|\d\D+\d|[%_\-&#=\$@]\w+[%_\-&#=$@]|etc...']);
```

Comment: En la documentación no dan mucha info sobre regex.
Vuelvo a hacer la pregunta. ¿Como coloco todas las reglas? Ya que colocandolas en una sola linea no cumpliría con lo que necesito.